# I can't split the timestamp (dd/mm/yy 0:00) column into date and hour

Tags: sql, mariadb

The overall problem is to Show the number of pages viewed by specific hour of day (0 – 23) that target accounts visit the website

Must Have column after query:
(Columns : Hour, # Total Pages Viewed by Target Accounts)

I can't find any way to split the timestamp column. The overall problem will be easily solve if I can split the timestamp.

I use https://sqliteonline.com/ as workbench. On the site, I can't import my sql file on other db other than Mariadb. Some function for Mariadb like HOUR() or DATE_FORMAT() to split the timestamp column which in date and hour format. When I attempt to use HOUR() funtion, my table return NULL. I attached the sql file for this. enter link description here

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **date_parse($datetime)['hour']** php function after get mariadb datetime value.

For example:

```
echo date_parse($contact->uploaded_on)['hour'];
```

If you wanna query result by hour. You can do add new string/int column and methods from php to split data before/after post/edit.